# Checking Linux kernel config at runtime

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is there any C function that can check whether a Linux kernel configuration option (`CONFIG_AAAA` option in `/boot/config-` file) is set?
Or I have to develop it myself.

Comment: A kernel could be configured to give you `/proc/config.gz`

Comment: boot/config ..??? you mean by arch/arm/config/*_defconfig ? and you want to check it from userspace c program ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Isn't it enough to just try if the functionality is present by calling it, and noting the failure? Your question makes me suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You have a problem X, believe the solution is to do Y, and ask about Y without mentioning X. All of [SO] struggles desperately to see how to accomplish Y, while the solution to X is something completelly different (and in many cases Y doesn't help either).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: as mention in https://wiki.debian.org/KernelFAQ, <code>/proc/config.gz is not supported in Debian and Ubuntu distributors

Comment: @Mr.32: I don't want to check the kernel source code but the currently used system. And I want to check /boot/config-`uname -r` file

Comment: @vad: you *can* (and I routinely do) configure and build (with `make-kpkg`) a kernel for Debian having `/proc/config.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search with no result, I developed a function myself. Here is the code:

```
static int is_kconfig_set(const char *config) {
    int ret = 0;
    struct utsname utsname;
    char pattern[BUFSIZ], buf[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (uname(&utsname) == -1)
        return 0;

    memset(pattern, 0, sizeof(pattern));
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    sprintf(pattern, "%s=y", config);
    sprintf(buf, "/boot/config-%s", utsname.release);

    fp = fopen(buf, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
        if (strncmp(buf, pattern, strlen(pattern)) == 0) {
            ret = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```

To check whether CONFIG_CPU_FREQ is set:

```
if (is_kconfig_set("CONFIG_CPU_FREQ"))
    return 1;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think is to create your own following the approach in `kernel/configs.c` (this is the code that creates /proc/config.gz).